# How can i find pairs in a list, Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, logic

I have a problem,
I have a list with numeric elements such as in the example.
I´d like to find all pairs, and count it. (Every Element can only be one part of one pair)

```
?- num_pairs([4,1,1,1,4],N).
N=1;
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need several things to make it work:

- An ability to count the number an item is repeated in a list
- An ability to remove all elements matching a value from the list
- An ability to conditionally increment a number

Here is how you can count:

```
count([], _, 0).
count([H|T], H, R) :- count(T, H, RT), R is RT + 1.
count([H|T], X, R) :- H \= X, count(T, X, R).
```

Deletion can be done with SWI's `delete/3` predicate; this is a built predicate.

Adding one conditionally requires two rules - one when the count equals one, and another one for when the count does not equal one.

```
add_if_count_is_one(H, T, RT, R) :- count(T, H, 1), R is RT + 1.
add_if_count_is_one(H, T, R, R) :- count(T, H, X), X \= 1.
```

Finally, counting pairs could look like this:

```
num_pairs([], 0).
num_pairs([H|T], R) :- delete(T, H, TT),
                       num_pairs(TT, RT),
                       add_if_count_is_one(H, T, RT, R).
```

An empty list has no pairs; when an item is counted as part of a pair, its copies are removed from the rest of the list.

[Here is this running program on ideone.](http://ideone.com/AkZy3B)

Comment: Than you ver much for this great answer, you are my king, but I have one more question, how can i handle this, if I want to increase the counter with the same entries, like this ?- num_pairs([1,5,5,2,4,4,4,4,3,1,2,2],N). N=4. Any Suggestion??

Comment: @StefanD. You need to change `add_if_count_is_one` to use a different condition, for example, like this: [link](http://ideone.com/MJlgMc). Note that I needed to add a new rule to cover zero and "too many entries" separately.

Comment: Thank you again. Ok, I think, I´v got it! But It doesn´t work for the first argument anymore (num_pairs([4,1,1,1,4],N).), how can i combine these rules, to work for both...?

Comment: @StefanD. The `[4,1,1,1,4]` example returns 2, as it is expected now: it's OK to repeat `1` three times. As far as combining the two, they count different things, so they should stay separate. I think it is a useful exercise - change `num_pairs/2` to `num_pairs/3`, though, taking the limit as the third parameter. Pass this limit to `add_if_count_is_one`, letting you find number of pairs, groups of up to three items, groups of up to four items, and so on.

Comment: Is it not better to check your current element in the list, then the next element, if they are the same count++, else make nothing?? Is this a possibility??

Comment: @StefanD. I strongly doubt that this would work, unless the list is first sorted.